# React Final Form FieldArray validation on form.restart

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, react-final-form-arrays

I have a form with a fields array. At the bottom of the form there is a button that deletes all list items (in fact, it does form.restart).
When deleting fields, the validation of each field is triggered, but the value of the field is undefined. This breaks the validation logic.
In theory, this validation should not exist at all.
How to get rid of this validation on form.restart?

Code:
(https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-water-6u3t69?file=/src/App.js:0-1477)

```
import React from "react";
import { Form, Field } from "react-final-form";
import { FieldArray } from "react-final-form-arrays";
import arrayMutators from "final-form-arrays";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [values] = React.useState({ items: [] });

  const renderForm = ({ form }) => {
    return (
      <div>
        <FieldArray name={"items"}>
          {({ fields }) => (
            <div>
              {fields.map((name, index) => (
                <div key={name}>
                  <Field
                    name={`${name}.title`}
                    validate={(value) => console.log(value)}
                    key={name}
                  >
                    {({ input }) => (
                      <input
                        value={input.value}
                        onChange={(event) => input.onChange(event.target.value)}
                      />
                    )}
                  </Field>
                </div>
              ))}
              <button onClick={() => fields.push({ title: "111" })}>
                add item
              </button>
              <button onClick={() => form.restart({ items: [] })}>reset</button>
            </div>
          )}
        </FieldArray>
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form
        onSubmit={() => {}}
        initialValues={values}
        render={renderForm}
        mutators={{ ...arrayMutators }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Thank you.